# Possible to call PDO::fetchAll() more then once?

Tags: php, pdo

Ive been running some queries using PHP's PDO library. It seems that when i use:

```
<?php
    $smtp->execute();
    $result = stmt->fecthArray();
?>
```

It unsets the array inside PDO. I know this because when i call that very same line again, it returns an empty array. Why does it do this? Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building the resulting array, fetchAll() removes all the results from the result set. Instead of calling it again, re-use the array you retrieved in the first time.